# how to Connect to Mysql only once?

Tags: linux, shell, mysql

I have created a shell script to connect to a DB and INSERT IPs and MACs from dhcpd.log file
the scripts worked properly:

```
#/!bin/bash
#Defining Variables
dhcpLogFile="/var/log/dhcpd.log"

#Begin Code
# extrcting the Information of IPs and MACs from log file
# and eleminating the duplicate Entry
NumberOfLines=$(awk '/DHCPACK/ { print $8} ' $dhcpLogFile | awk '!x[$0]++'|awk 'BEGIN{i=0}{i++;}END{print i}')
j=1
while [ $NumberOfLines -gt 0 ]
do
ip=$(awk '/DHCPACK/ { print $8} ' $dhcpLogFile | awk '!x[$0]++' |cut -f$j -d$'\n')
mac=$(awk '/DHCPACK/ { print $10} ' $dhcpLogFile | awk '!x[$0]++' |cut -f$j -d$'\n')
echo $ip
echo $mac   
let "j +=1"
let "NumberOfLines -=1"
mysql -u root --password='pw' MatchingDB <<- _END_ 
INSERT INTO IP_MACTable (IP_Address, MAC) VALUES ('$ip','$mac');
_END_
done
```

The code is correct but as you can see it connects to the DB every insert query inside the while, my question is how can I connect to the DB only once then do multiple queries then exit without connecting to it every insertion operation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by piping to mysql:

```
while …
do
    ⋮
    echo "INSERT INTO IP_MACTable (IP_Address, MAC) VALUES ('$ip','$mac');"
done | mysql -u root …
```

Note how I changed your `while` loop to output the queries it wants to run to stdout. Then I piped your while do...done loop to `mysql`.

You can pipe a subshell as well, so for example you could do:

```
(
    echo "BEGIN;"
    while … ; do
        ⋮
        echo "INSERT INTO IP_MACTable (IP_Address, MAC) VALUES ('$ip','$mac');"
    done
    echo "COMMIT;"
) | mysql -u root …
```

so that if you abort processing in the middle MySQL will roll back the transaction, so you don't wind up with a half-loaded file. Also, running inside a transaction (as opposed to committing each row individually) is generally much faster.

Comment: I have piped the while loop to the mysql connect but when I run my shell an error occured

Comment: @Networker Did you put `echo` in front of that line? Hard to figure out where the syntax error is without seeing the edited script.

Comment: @Networker Also, I didn't notice, you're doing a few more echo's in that loop, you need to send those to stderr instead as well (otherwise, MySQL will try to execute themas queries). E.g., `echo $ip >&2`

Comment: Sorry, Now I put `echo` but another error occured `bash: warning: here-document at line 27 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `_END_')
bash: logDHCP.sh: line 34: syntax error: unexpected end of file` and this is the edited code`#/!bin/bash
dhcpLogFile="/var/log/dhcpd.log"
while [ $NumberOfLines -gt 0 ]
do
 ......
 echo "INSERT INTO IP_MACTable (IP_Address, MAC) VALUES ('$ip','$mac');
 _END_"
done | mysql -u root --password='centos' MatchingDB <<- _END_`

Comment: @Networker you need to remove the << part off the end of the MySQL line. And also get rid of the END inside the echo...

Comment: A technique I often use for stuff like this is to launch at the beginning of the script something like `exec 3> >(mysql -u root)`. Then any time you want to send something to mysql, it's just `echo 'select foo' >&3`

Comment: thanks alot it worked I will mark the question as answered Now @derobert